# Как отметить все элементы в legend на графике boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Пишу конспект по статистике, хочу для наглядности отобразить все элементы графика boxplot в legend, и подписать, что они означают, пытался копаться в документациях, но что-то никак не выходит разобраться. Мой код, который есть на данный момент:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
heights = [185, 175, 170, 169, 171, 172, 175, 157, 170, 172, 167, 173, 168, 167, 166,
           167, 169, 172, 177, 178, 165, 161, 179, 159, 164, 178, 172, 170, 173, 171]
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
_ = plt.boxplot(heights,
                boxprops=dict(linestyle='--', linewidth=3, color='darkgoldenrod'),
                flierprops = dict(marker='*'),
                medianprops = dict(linestyle='-.', linewidth=2.5, color='firebrick'))
plt.legend(_)
plt.show()
```

Помогите построить наглядный и понятный график.

Comment: а что вас не устраивает в данном решении?

Comment: Тут не все отображается в легенде или не совсем корректно, я не знаю, как настроить другие элементы, и я хотел бы в ручную прописать название для каждого элемента в легенде (кириллицей например).

Comment: Какие именно дополнительные элементы вы хотите отобразить в легенде?

Comment: -квантили(желательно каждый по отдельности, если есть такая возможность)
-усы(+их длина равная n-квартильному размаху)
-среднее
-наблюдения, лежащие дальше интерквартильного размаха

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пришлось зарыться в исходники `matplotlib`:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
bp = plt.boxplot(heights, showmeans=True,
                 capprops=dict(linestyle='--', linewidth=3, color='darkgoldenrod', label='границы'),
                 boxprops=dict(linestyle='--', linewidth=4, color='black', label='квартили'),
                 flierprops = dict(marker='*', markersize=10, markerfacecolor='lightblue', markeredgecolor='lightblue', label='выбросы'),
                 meanprops = dict(linestyle='-.', linewidth=2.5, color='yellow', label='среднее'),
                 medianprops = dict(linestyle='-.', linewidth=3.5, color='firebrick', label='медиана'),
                 whiskerprops=dict(linestyle='-', linewidth=2, color='green', label='Усы')) 
plt.legend()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[для сверки](https://datavizcatalogue.com/RU/metody/diagramma_razmaha.html):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Ste_kd, я сначала подумал что сейчас быстренько найду ответ на просторах интернета - не тут то было :-D Пришлось изучать исходники `...\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py` и эксперементировать...

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/boxplot.html

я вот такую инфу нашел) но всеравно не смог разобраться до конца

Comment: @Ste_kd, да, это первое что находится, но там ни слова о том как назвать отдельные элементы одного ящика с усами